# Beginner Questions about django-viewflow

Tags: django, django-models, django-viewflow

I am working on my first django-viewflow project, and I have some very basic questions. I have looked at the docs and the cookbook examples.

My question is which fields go into the "normal" django models (models.Model) and which fields go into the Process models? For example, I am building a publishing model, so a document that is uploaded starts in a private state, then goes into a pending state after some processing, and then an editor can update the documents state to publish, and the document is available through the front facing web site. I would assume the state field (private, pending, publish) are part of a process model, but what about the other fields related to the document (author, date, source, topic, etc.)? Do they go into the process model or the models.Model model? Does it matter? What are the considerations in building the models and flows for separation of data between the two types of models?

Another example - why in the Hello World example is the text field in the Process model and not a model.Models model? This field does not seem to have anything to do with the process, but I am probably not understanding how viewflow works.

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 1):

That's your choice. Viewflow is the library and has no restriction on data alignment. The only thing that needs to be done is the link between `process_pk` and the process data. HelloWord is the minimal working sample, that demonstrates a workflow.

You can put everything in the separate mode and provide an FK to in the Process model.

But the state field itself is the antipattern since eventually, you can have several tasks executed in parallel. And even sequential workflow could be constantly changed, new tasks could be added or deleted. You can have only `published` Boolean or DateTime field in the POST model to filter on that on the front end.

The general rule could be - keep all people workflow decisions in the Process model, and build all data models in a declarative way, keep separated workflow and actual data.

Comment: Could you also throw some light on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48780791/django-viewflows-defining-an-api-flow