# Django viewflows - Defining an API flow

Tags: python, django, workflow, django-viewflow

I've an API endpoint, `/api/create/`. This creates a new entry in the DB depending upon the payload received from the client.

```
Payload - { 
'field1': 'value1`,
'field2': 'value2`,
'field3': 'value3`,
'field4': 'value4`,
'type': 'A'
}
```

Now depending on the `type`, I've a specific workflow. For eg:- `Type A` needs to perform certain tasks before saving the data, `Type B` has its own set of operations.

I don't have any UI, just the requests coming over the POST request. How can I use [django-viewflows](https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow) for such a use-case?

**UPDATED**

I was able to run the workflow programmatically using `WorkFlowClass.start.run()`. It starts the workflow perfectly. However, not the complete workflow. Upon completing Node1(start) of workflow, it does not goes to Node2. Meaning, only first task of the workflow is called, not the subsequent tasks.

Here is my workflow.

```
class FunctionFlow1(Flow):
    start = flow.StartFunction(function1) \
        .Next(this.task2)
    task2 = flow.StartFunction(function2) \
        .Next(this.end)
    end = flow.End()

@flow_start_func
def function1(activation, **kwargs):
    print('Func1 Called.')
    activation.prepare()
    activation.done()
    return activation

@flow_start_func
def function1(activation, **kwargs):
    print('Func2 Called.')
    activation.prepare()
    activation.done()
    return activation
```

`task2` is not called. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `viewflow.rest` package to create the REST APIs. Please look at the demo project and view flow rest documentation.

Please note that this feature is available in **PRO Only**

https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/tree/master/react_ui

http://docs.viewflow.io/viewflow_rest.html

> viewflow.rest package provides a flow implementation with the REST
>   interface.

Comment: Hi, I was able to run in programmatically using `WorkFlowClass.start.run()`. It starts the workflow perfectly. But, upon completing the Node1, it does not goes to Node2 of the same Workflow. Meaning, only first task of the workflow is called, not the subsequent task.

Comment: How do I make sure that all the tasks within the workflow executes?

Comment: Any lead to it?